# Check before submit button bootstrap modal textbox filled or not if not give message to near modal button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

[image]

Above is my image now I wanted to know how can I check the data filled in bootstrap modal. My submit button not working since I m not inserting data in modal but I wanted to tell user to by showing message you have to fill modal text box data for submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution in above model first address field id is address_line_1 I used that in my javascript

```
<script> $('#submit').click(function(e){ if($.trim($('#address_line_1').val()) == ''){ $("#myModal").modal("show"); e.preventDefault(); } }); </script>
```